# What's a good distribution for high-variability right-skewed proportion data?

Tags: regression, distributions, generalized-additive-model, gamlss

My data is in the interval $(0,1)$.

I am interested in regression using GAM or GAMLSS. The distribution should preferably be available in the packages mgcv or gamlss.

However, so far, I have used the normal distribution*, normal after logit transformation, gamma*, and beta distribution (* means that the support of the distributiton is not (0,1) which is of course an issue).

All of these distributions have trouble with the data due to a lot of variability that cause a significant right-skew.

The QQplot of my residuals do not look like a straight line, but rather like this:

[image]

ALL the aforementioned distributions produce qqplots like this, some more profound than others though, and the best one so far seems to be in this order: 1) gamma, 2) logit, 3) beta, 4) normal.

What other distributions should I try? Preferably exponential family.

Comment: Could you add a histogram of the data?

Comment: More precisely, of your residuals.